# Exoplayer with PreviewSeekBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, exoplayer

I'm not able to figure out how to properly use PreviewSeekBar together with exoplayer.
Link module: https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar

Could someone help me to understand what are the correct steps I have to do to make them work properly?

In the build.gradle file I added:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.rubensousa: previewseekbar: 1.2'
     implementation 'com.github.rubensousa: previewseekbar-exoplayer: 2.6.0'
}
```

But I must also add those of the exoplayer I have already included in the module?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there, did you check rouben sample module. i guess you have to change your basic exoplayer implmentation

Comment: Can I contact you privately?

Comment: yeah sure, but we don't have privilege for chatroom, so can you drop your mail id and i'll reply there.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by email id? I do not know you have Twitter, Facebook that I contact you? Or your email?

Comment: email id is fine

Comment: This is my github profile: https://github.com/Angelk90
Find them my email.
I'm waiting for your email, we'll be there.